# Fastest way to write string on Windows?

Tags: windows, performance, winapi, language-agnostic

What would be the absolute fastest possible way to write a string to the standard/console output on Windows? I'm interested in the solution for both null- and non-null-terminated strings.

Comment: If this is where your bottlenecks are, high-five to you.

Comment: I'm guessing he's writing 100 lines per second and that would slow your main program loop down...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[WriteConsole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687401(VS.85).aspx) is pretty much the fastest you can get. It's still inter-process call to win32csr (on Windows 7 it's different, but it is still IPC) using LPC, so don't expect performance to be something surprising.

Answer (score 1):

2nd on the WriteConsole answer, you can write the entire screen in one call;
but also 2nd on what Austin says: having ultrafast console output as a requirement for an application sounds a bit strange to me.
Anyway if it's really a bottleneck, maybe use some kind of logging system and provide actual logging to the console a seperate thread?